# Какой пет-проект писать на java что-бы затронуть основные моменты?

Tags: java

Например на php, для такого проекта можно взять интернет магазин или блог.
В нем затрагивается много основных моментов. есть роутинг, mvc, БД, работа с куки и сессиями, работа с файлами и т.п. Возможность бесконечного расширения. И бесконечно можно переписывать используя разные паттерны, инструменты, фреймворки.
Вот что подобное можно реализовать на java?

Comment: То же самое можно. Попробуйте в Spring реализовать тот же интернет-магазин со всем вышеуказанным.

Comment: а еще лучше без Спринга, если нужно понимание основный процессов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поддержу комментарий выше. Попробуй сделать без Spring. Когда я начинал изучать джаву, мне посоветовали самому написать игру "Быки и коровы", работа с коллекциями и небольшая работа с графическими интерфейсами. 
Позже решил сделать что-то поинтереснее. Использовал парсинг. Выгрузил с сайта все результаты любимой команды и делал небольшой анализ. Например: сравнивал результаты прошлых лет с нынешним годом. Кол-во забитых и пропущенных и т.д.. Тут как фантазия заиграет, используется практически вся основа джавы. Можно даже с БД что-нибудь придумать. А так привел примеры из личного опыта. 
Java Core + Maven + JSoup вполне достаточно.